# Socket server in C (UDP) doesn't receive packets. How to do?

Tags: c, sockets, server, binding, localhost

I've done a UDP socket server in C. The server works properly only if the packets are send to 127.0.0.1. I'm trying to test it with packet sender, and I want to open a socket at the address 192.168.231.54. Anyway, if I write this address in the code, I receive an error ("Cannot assign requested address"), and this error appears for each single address different from 127.0.0.1. I want to open a socket to 192.168.231.54 and I want to send packets to this address with Packet Sender.

Here is the server code:

```
//*********SOCKET OPENING**************
   
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr, cliaddr;

    if ( (fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror( "socket failed" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        
    memset( &serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr) );
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));

    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(50037);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  

    if ( bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0 ) {
        perror( "bind failed" );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else{
        perror("socket opened");
    }

    //Receiving data into hex_array array
    char hex_array[lenght];
    int len;
    len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    int n = recvfrom(fd, (uint8_t *)hex_array, lenght, NULL, ( struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len);
    //Printing of the received data on the socket
    printf("START DEBUG:\n");
    printf("%s\n", hex_array);
    printf("END DEBUG.\n");
```

Comment: Obviously I can ping that address, it's perfectly reachable.

Comment: Also note that UDP is by definition unreliable, so you'd have to implement some kind of reliability mechanism if you want to get every single frame sent.

Comment: Thank you, I know. Actually my problem is to receive something... then I will care about receive the message correctly.

Comment: The address you're trying to bind to has to be the private IP of the device you're running the code, otherwise it will always fail. Are you sure your PC has IP 192.168.231.54?

Comment: I'm voting to close because the code and the error message disagree.

Comment: Show the code that actually has the error.  Presumably, you're setting `serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr` differently, so show that.

Comment: you're `bind`ing to `INADDR_ANY`, not 192.168.231.54. If you run `ifconfig` in a terminal, does it show an interface with that address?

Comment: @yano `INADDR_ANY` would allow him to listen on 192.168.231.54 too, **if** the machine he's running the code on has that private IP.

Comment: @Nastor yes, but sounds like to me OP wants to listen _only_ on 192.168.231.54, in which case `INADDR_ANY` is not what should be used ... unless I'm misinterpreting OP's intentions.

Comment: @yano the OP wants to send packets to 192.168.231.54 and have the server receive them. Of course, that can only work if either 1) the sender and server are running on the same LAN/PC, and the server PC has 192.168.231.54 assigned to it, or 2) 192.168.231.54 is assigned to a proxy/router that forwards the packets to whatever LAN IP the server's PC is running at.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I agree... ? OP wants to listen at 192.168.231.54 so I would expect to see `serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.231.54");`. What am I missing here that my suggestion using `INADDR_ANY` is too broad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address you bind the socket to has to actually be your computer's IP address. You can't just pick a random address.